# Scraping data dynamically generated by JavaScript

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I tried using PhantomJSDriver for scraping this URL: http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=67126881188552864

1) First, in this URL we must click on the upper blue link named: سابقه

2) Then I want scrap this XPath: `//*[@id="trade"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[7]`

Here is my code but this code can't find required XPath:

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);

driver.Url = "http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspxParTree=151311&i=67126881188552864";
driver.Navigate();
var source = driver.PageSource;
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"tabs\"]/div/ul/li[3]/a").Click();

Thread.Sleep(5000);

try
{
    var pathElement = driver.FindElementByXPath("//[@id=\"trade\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[7]");
    MessageBox.Show(pathElement.Text);
}
catch
{
    driver.Dispose();
    this.Close();
}
driver.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to directly hit this url:

```
http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/InstTradeHistory.aspx?i=67126881188552864&Top=999999&A=0
```

And then parse the values as this contains all the values basically on all the  209 pages so it will save you also the trouble of moving from page 1 -209.

And it looks easy split by ; gives you all the rows and then split by @ gives you the values per column.

Comment: but how can you find this URL?

Comment: @ScorpianZ open firefox (open console) or fiddler hit the URL when it runs you will see the above URL getting loaded (ajax call ).